# Прерывается выполнение - EXC_BAD....

Tags: xcode, iphone, objective-c

Уважаемые знатоки, прошу помочь, если сможете. Есть код:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _sevenForDisplay.length; i++) {

        _sevensForReplace = [_sevensForReplace stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([[_sevenForDisplay substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)] intValue]-1,1) withString:@"1"];

        NSOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                  initWithTarget:self
                                  selector:@selector(blinkPicSeven:)
                                  object:@(_forBlink)];

        [queue addOperation:operation];

    }

 [userDefaults setObject:_sevensForReplace forKey:@"sevens"];
```

Когда он выполняется в процессе работы программы, вылетает на последней строке с сообщением
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=1, address=0x7a0090018).

Начинаю отлаживать пошагово (становлюсь в начале цикла и далее по F6), все проходит нормально.
Даже не знаю, куда смотреть. ((

Comment: А если попробовать не `_sevensForReplace`, а `self.sevensForReplace`?

Comment: Не помогает ((

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в дебаггере остановку на исключениях. И увидете точное место остановки.

[image]

**Обновление**

Не сразу заметил, что пример для iOS. У вас `'[[_sevenForDisplay substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)] intValue]'` может быть равен 0. Значит `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` принимает диапазон -1,1. Это необработанное исключение в iOS SDK. Ошибка или нет, не знаю, но в Mac OS ваш пример работать будет, выводя сообщение.

Comment: Да это уже включено, только не очень помогает. Может, имеет значение: когда иду пошагово, переменной `_sevensForReplace` присваиваются значения, какие нужно. А когда идет в потоке выполнения программы, то внизу в отладчике `_sevensForReplace (NSString *)=0x7fe8fa45c370`. Думаю, что поэтому и вылетает, что данной переменной ничего не присваивается, а почему не пойму.

Comment: @asv72 Обновил ответ

Comment: Да и еще, этот проект стоял полгода, как раз сменилась ОСХ и соответственно Xcode, да вот в старой версии все работало как часы, проект готовился к публикации, решили поднять и завершить, а тут вот ппц что ((

Answer (score 0):

В английской части портала помогли. Решение вопроса связано в определении переменной:
`[[NSString alloc]init]`
В данном конкретном случае

```
NSString *sevensForReplace = [[NSString alloc]init];
```